# Twitter, Error: 401 accessing '/1/statuses/sample.json'. Reason: Unauthorized

Tags: r, twitter, streaming

I want to download tweets (without searching an specific question). I tried your advice:

```
curlPerform(url = https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json -u USER:PASSWORD -o "somefile.txt"

# set the directory
setwd("C:\\")

#### redirects output to a file
WRITE_TO_FILE <- function(x) {
  if (nchar(x) >0 ) {
    write.table(x, file="Twitter Stream Capture.txt", append=T, row.names=F, col.names=F)
  }
}

### windows users will need to get this certificate to authenticate
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")

### write the raw JSON data from the Twitter Firehouse to a text file
getURL("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json", 
       cainfo = "cacert.pem", 
       write=WRITE_TO_FILE)
```

Only if I suppress 'userpwd="Username:Password' I get a result, which is a text file containing the following information:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing '/1/statuses/sample.json'. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
```

I am looking to stay completely within R and need to use Windows. Any advice on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the username and password with the `userpwd` argument:

```
library(RCurl)

WRITE_TO_FILE <- function(x) {
  if (nchar(x) > 0) {
    write.table(x, file='twitter_stream_capture.txt', append=TRUE, 
                row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
  }
}

download.file(url='http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem', destfile='cacert.pem')

getURL('https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json', 
       userpwd='username:password', cainfo='cacert.pem',
       write=WRITE_TO_FILE)
```

Replace `username` and `password` in `getURL` with a valid Twitter username and password.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced username and password with my Twitter username and password, but unfortunately I didn't solve the problem. I got: function(x) { if (nchar(x) > 0) {write.table(x,file="twitter_stream_capture.txt", append=TRUE,                 row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE) read.table("Twitter Stream Capture.txt")1<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>\n<title>Error 401

Comment: The code I posted above works perfectly for me with RCurl_1.6-10.1.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that mine is RCurl_1.91-1.1 bitops_1.0-4.1. Should it be a problem? Or may be it is just how I'm trying to 'access' the data in file='twitter_stream_capture.txt'? (I used 'readHTMLTable')?

Comment: Not sure why I was using an old version.. I thought I was up to date. I've updated to RCurl_1.91-1 and it still works fine. Your method of reading the table will not be responsible for the Error 401. Opening in a text editor will reveal the same. The Twitter stream dump, if it works, the output file will be many megabytes. I'm not sure how much it dumps... I've been killing the process when it reaches about 15mb. I suspect the username and password you're providing are incorrect. Open the file in a text editor.. does it say 'Reason: unauthorized'? Can you log in [here](http://twitter.com/)?

Comment: If your username and password are correct, then perhaps you're not referring correctly to the certificate (cacert.pem). Are you including the `cainfo` argument?

Comment: I double check my username and password (I've been able to log in where you requested). I got a cacert.pem file of 215k and a .txt file of only 7KB, containing only the error message. I did exactly what you advised me. I've been using 'cainfo=cacert.pem'. What else could I try? Thanks a lot

Comment: Today I tried with different username and password and got this message: In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")): not possible to open file 'twitter_stream_capture.txt': Permission denied. As you suggest, it seems that the problem is the certificate(cacert.pem)? I'm including it as cainfor=(cacert.pem). I obtained a 73.700KB but when I open it contains only the usual 'unauthorized' message. Thanks a lot

Comment: The Permission Denied error, when attempting to append to the txt file, sounds more like a file permissions error. Did you have the txt file open in a text editor at the time? This could potentially lock the file. Try again with the alternative username and pw, and if you still get the permissions error, try a new filename in a path that you know you have write permissions for.

Comment: Good to hear. What were you doing wrong? It's useful for others to know what problems might exist, and how to overcome them.

Comment: I tried with the alternative username and pw, a new filename and I change the path (e.g. setwd("C:\\"). Thanks again